# Google search Python script, without using APIs

Tags: python, search

Most of the Google search python scripts use either `WWW::Mechanize` or Google APIs.

How to write a script without using these and JSON objects?

Comment: Why would you want to deliberately make life hard for yourself? Use the Google APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the URL for the query yourself, if you like, and then make a request using `urllib2` or something of the like. The URLs for Google search queries are explained [here](http://www.blueglass.com/blog/google-search-url-parameters-query-string-anatomy/).

Of course, really, there's no shame in just using the APIs.

Comment: Another problem with queries is if you do too many requests, sooner or later you will get a captcha from Google instead of the answer.